# Importing csv file into ms access using DoCmd.TransferText network permissions

Tags: vba, import, permissions

I have a simple vba script to import a csv from a network share into a new table in my access database. I have access to the network share and it runs fine from my machine.  I want others who dont have access to the network share to be able to execute the script too. I have a generic network account with the required permissions and am hoping i can embed this into the script?

I've had a look in this and other forums and MSDN and cant find how to do this, most seem to concern database and database connection permissions.

Thankyou

```
Sub Import_data()

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM Soil_moisture_data"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "Soil_moisture_data", "full network path and file", True
MsgBox "Soil moisture data has been updated"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. It creates a local mapped network drive of the network location, than it imports data as it would import from csv file in a local drive; when finished it removes the mapped drive.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set wshNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

strUsername = Domain\username

strPassword = Password

strDestination = GetNextLetter("F", wshNet)

wshNet.MapNetworkDrive strDestination, "\\ServerAddress\Folder", , strUsername, strPassword

DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "Daily_data", strDestination & "\RestOfThePathIncludingFileName", True

wshNet.RemoveNetworkDrive strDestination, True

Set objFSO = Nothing
Set wshNetwork = Nothing
```

This solution was done following from https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21108808/using-vba-to-copy-file-to-a-network-share-with-username-and-password.html

```
Function GetNextLetter(DriveLetter, wshNet)

   'Start x at the ascii value of the drive letter to start the search
   'unless something is passed in. This sample uses capital letters and
   'starts at F.

   If IsEmpty(DriveLetter) Then

    x = 70

   Else

    x = Asc(DriveLetter)

   End If   

   Set oDrives = wshNet.EnumNetworkDrives
   'Step by two since the first item in the collection is the drive letter
   'and the second item is the network mapping

   For i = 0 To oDrives.Count - 1 Step 2

    If Chr(x) & ":" = oDrives.Item(i) Then

        x = x + 1

    End If

   Next   

   GetNextLetter = Chr(x) & ":"

End Function
```